# Javascript: Certain class is defined twice with same name in 2 javascripts/ccs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have downloaded 2 packages from the internet. One is used for making the items of a list, show in pages, and the other one is a jPlayer for .mp3 files.

The `next page/previous page`  buttons for the pages of the list, have the same name with the `next song/previous song`  buttons of the mp3 player. They are both called `jp-next` and `jp-previous`.

These are the files the `List-Paging`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/itemsperpage/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/itemsperpage/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/itemsperpage/jPages.js"></script>
```

These are the files the `jPlayer`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The way i see it, changing some names in the `List-Paging` files will do the trick.
Problem is that i have absolutely no experience with javascipt,jQuery, i kindly request for help on this matter.

**The *only* problem is that `next page/previous page` background, is *affected* by the background of the `next song/previous song`**.
I have uploaded a sample on jsfiddle to show you the problem.

--> http://jsfiddle.net/5svd5mnh/

Comment: Check out http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-cssSelector for custom selectors

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Do you know where am i supposed to put something like http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-detail-cssSelector this ? this seems like what i am looking for , i dont really know , i am totally new to this .

Comment: i dont understand what files i must edit , where are those files ? i have `jplayer.playlist.min.js` , ` jquery.jplayer.min.js` , ` jquery.min.js` , `jplayer.blue.monday.css`

Comment: Wherever jplayer is being initiated in the JS file. So you'd pass it in with the other parameters. like such ```$(element).jPlayer({
                cssSelector: {play: "jplayer-play", pause: "jplayer-pause", etc etc}
            });```

Comment: It may be inline in the html via a <script> tag. Check there as well

Comment: man all i see in the .js files is a million rows without any alignment whatsoever, this is impossible for me to read... there are 3 files , http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jquery.min.js , http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js , http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jplayer.playlist.min.js ,  can you give me a simple example on how to add a css selector ?

Comment: Check your HTML file. It looks like that may be where you can also change them via this example. http://jsfiddle.net/jPlayer/XLNCY/

Comment: http://pastie.org/9605704  this is how the script is inside the .html file

Comment: there is a cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" , in the <script></script> tags  in my html file , do you have any idea what i can do with that ?

Comment: Well... it actually looks like jplayer doesn't give you an option to change jp-next, jp-previous classes easily and neither does the jPages plugin... :\ Try adding the following before the end of your inline script tag.. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rteBXjVM You can see the parameters in that css page if you scroll up to predefined css selectors. I'm leaving work now so I won't be around for awhile. GL!

Comment: it didn't work... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of avoiding this problem is to use :

```
<?php echo'<link href="http://shiro-desu.com/scr/jquery/jplayer.blue.monday.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'; ?>
```

in your page, in the `<body>` part only when you actually use the jPlayer.
 
So that the 2 .css files will never be imported at the same time.
This however means that you *won't be able to use a `jPlayer` and a `List-Paging` in the same .html page*.